# Happiness and Karma

Tags: karma, happiness

I suddenly thought of a question...
If one often feels unhappy, stress, uncontented, negativity, does it mean this person has bad karma?
Is there a way to improve the situation so that the person can be calmer, and happy?
TIA!

Comment: yes. but no. all experiences are a construct of karma. but not just from this life: you have zillions of previous personalities to blame

Comment: also, the karma necessary to be born as a human, let alone a human with access to the dharma, is very good indeed. the idea of blaming yourself for bad karma is just meant to help you practice!

Answer (score 2):

The word "kamma" means "intentional action".

If one often feels unhappy, stress, uncontented, negativity, this does mean this person has unskillful ('bad') karma.

In summary, the unskillful karma is not practicing the Buddhist path.

To improve the situation, i.e., to do good karma, one can practice the Buddhist path, which on the most basic level means:

1. To [avoid killing, stealing, lying](https://suttacentral.net/an10.211/en/bodhi?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin), drugs, alcohol, gambling, [borrowing money](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.062.than.html) for transient things.
2. To avoid unskilful careless non-committed sexual activity that leads to unhappiness.
3. To practice generosity, unselfishness, kindness & non-harming towards others.
4. To [avoid bad dangerous friends](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.31.0.nara.html) and associate with good safe friends.
5. To develop being inspired by the virtues of the Buddha & Good Monks, Nuns & Buddhists.
6. Train the mind to abandon [anger](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.17.budd.html) and cruelty.

Answer (score 0):

These are just feelings and metal states. They come and go. They belong to noone. Just be mindful of them until they pass away.

You can follow the Noble Eightfold Path, meditate and do good deeds.